# Can I replace SCL and SDA into any other pins ? If possible How I write code?

Tags: i2c

## I want to use other pins which are not default SCL,SDA unlike code that Adfruit they wrote. How can I use pin 5,6 or others that active as pin scl sda ?

https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_PCA9685

[image]

Thank you for watching my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a software I2C bus on any pair of spare GPIO.  Note that you will need to add pull-ups to 3V3 on these GPIO for them to properly work as an I2C bus (1k8 resistors are suggested).

```
Name:   i2c-gpio
Info:   Adds support for software i2c controller on gpio pins
Load:   dtoverlay=i2c-gpio,<param>=<val>
Params: i2c_gpio_sda            GPIO used for I2C data (default "23")

        i2c_gpio_scl            GPIO used for I2C clock (default "24")

        i2c_gpio_delay_us       Clock delay in microseconds
                                (default "2" = ~100kHz)

        bus                     Set to a unique, non-zero value if wanting
                                multiple i2c-gpio busses. If set, will be used
                                as the preferred bus number (/dev/i2c-<n>). If
                                not set, the default value is 0, but the bus
                                number will be dynamically assigned - probably
                                3.
```

See `/boot/overlays/README` for details.